# dbt - what is +/- in YAML files?

Tags: yaml, dbt

In DBT YAML file such as dbt_project.yml, what is `+` or `-` sign of the element?

```
models:
  # Be sure to namespace your model configs to your project name
  dbt_labs:

    # This configures models found in models/events/
    events:
      +enabled: true            # <--- What is the meaning of +?
      +materialized: view       # <--- What is the meaning of +?

      # This configures models found in models/events/base
      # These models will be ephemeral, as the config above is overridden
      base:
        +materialized: ephemeral       # <--- What is the meaning of +?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"-" is standard YAML syntax, indicating a "list" item: [docs.ansible.com > YAML Basisc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics)

"+" is DBT-specific, indicating a sub-category like "+indexes", "+tags".  It's just a DBT convention. [docs.getdbt.com > Materialize Configs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/materialize-configs).

Comment: Why isn't there a "+" for the select line for the grants option on that page in the documentation? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/grants

Comment: Oh I think I'm getting it. They just identify the first level of the DBT configuration keys in the YAML file, right?

Answer (score 1):

The plus is mentioned in the docs:

"The + prefix is a dbt syntax feature, introduced in dbt v0.17.0, which helps disambiguate between resource paths and configs in dbt_project.yml files."

See:
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/plus-prefix